# Why does the priority from getPriority inside a new thread differ from the priority in the calling thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-7, thread-priority

For example, why does the following code not output a priority of 7?

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new A());
        thread.setPriority(7);
        System.out.println("in main: " + thread.getPriority());
        thread.start();
    }
}

class A extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("in thread: " + this.getPriority());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
in main: 7
in thread: 5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
new Thread(new A());
```

You're treating the `new A()` as a `Runnable` and passing it to a separate `Thread` instance.

The new `Thread` instance does not affect the `Thread` base of its `Runnable` at all.

You should use `new A()` directly.